# django bbs sns pinax

Tags: django

I want to do a django bbs forum, what I was looking for an open-source or use pinax do? ? Please give a reason, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinax could work for your needs. It's open source, built on Django, and has a lot of social media features. However, if you just need a forum I recommend looking at:

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ForumAppsComparison

and selecting what suits your needs best. I don't know what your exact needs are, because you haven't provided any details on what you need. I recommend reading about Pinax, and the other forum software at the link provided and seeing what suits your needs. I can't provide a reason to use one over the other though, due to your vague description of needs.

Comment: hi f4nt:
My company requires not only forums which use django, but also sns, so your mean is I should choose pinax?  yes?